# How to use IStringStream to read from a file?

Tags: c++, stream, istringstream

I need to read in an expression from a file using a string stream and convert the expression to into another form.  But I am having trouble figuring out how to read lines from the file using the Istringstream.  Can anyone help me with the #includes and syntax for this?  Thanks

Comment: You can't, you need a **file** stream to read from files, **string** streams are for strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream file("filename.txt");

StuffType stuff;
while(file >> stuff)
{
    // If you are here you have successfully read stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the answer of Dave above: to read one line from a file, you can use the following code:

```
char buf[256];
file.getline(buf,256);
```

The character string buf then contains the line of text in the file.

Comment: I tried that too, but I couldn't find the right syntax. Perhaps you can help? This does at least NOT work: std::string buf; file.getline(buf, 256); Neither does it work if you remove the second argument in getline.

Comment: `getline` for `string` is not a member. The syntax is `std::getline( file, buf );`